# JMS - One ConnectionFactory per Queue or one ConnectionFactory for all of the queues

Tags: jms, websphere, activemq-classic

I am using WebSphere with ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ's JCA adapter. In our application, there are a lot of queues for different functionalities. So can you tell me, should I create one ConnectionFactory for each queue(functionality) or only one ConnectionFactory for the whole application and shared for the queues ? And the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I am concerned is the performance. So which one will have a better performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Really depends what are your requirements. It is not specific to ActiveMQ, but queuing in general. You usually may create separate connection factories when you have:

- different host/port for different queues
- different security credentials to connect
- want to have different connection pools

So for example, if you want to ensure that at least *n* connections are available for certain queues you can create separate connection factory for that. As with one connection factory, in some extreme cases, when most of your application load is - let say - on *functionalityA* queues, then you may not have enough connections for your *functionalityB* queues and that functionality may suffer starving.

Comment: Yes, in the case of connection pools, sometimes we may need several connection pools to guarantee the quantity of connections. But I am wondering, why not reuse the same connection if we use the same broker ? Because it cost very expansive to establish the connection.

Comment: @XunRen That's why you have a pool, as establishing connection is expensive. However sharing same connection among different threads concurrently is not good from the performance perspective.